# coloring a td on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, css, hover, html-table

I want to add a background color on a `td` as a mouse hover in smarty.

How can I use create a hover I made a class for hover but its not working.

Help me out

Comment: Can you show us what you tried that is not working?

Answer (score 7):

see the [css :hover selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/sel_hover.asp).

In your case:

```
td.yourClass { background-color: transparent; }
td.yourClass:hover { background-color: red; /* for example */ }
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BWW63/)

Comment: and want to cchange the whole td color change

Comment: @Sunny, I'm sorry but you need to try with a clean Firefox profile  or safe_mode (see http://kb.mozillazine.org/Standard_diagnostic_(Firefox)). This colors the whole td in red (not the text, the background)

Comment: @Sunny: You should explain the context which you use more detailed. For example if you use jQuery UI styles the `background-image` is typically set on the `<td>`. In the case you can set `td.yourClass { background-image: none; }` additionally to other styles. If it don't solve the problem and you have another problem you should provide the test case which can be used to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
function rollbg(chosen, objectID) {
if(chosen == "roll") {
document.getElementById(objectID).className="roll";
}
else {
document.getElementById(objectID).className="over";
}
}
</SCRIPT>




    <STYLE>

.hlink {
display block;
height:20px;
width:75px;
color:black;
background-color:white;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
}
.hlink:hover {
color:white;
background-color:black;
}

    </STYLE>
```

Comment: can you explain little bit more

Comment: By adding a class which you have defined.

Comment: but when i can use this one then the text color will be chnge but i wnt the whole td change EX when my mose one a tab the color of td is black

Comment: By Defining <TD class = "ClassName"> like this

Answer (score 0):

You can try this....

```
<style>
td.navon {
background-color: #999999;
cursor: hand}
td.navoff {
background-color: #FFFFFF}
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="navoff" onmouseover="className='navon'" onmouseoff="className='navoff'">
      td 1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="navoff" onmouseover="className='navon'" onmouseoff="className='navoff'">
      td 2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks buddy its will be working but silent chenge i will use the onmouseout event thanks dear

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
td{
    background:red;
    color:white;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid white;
}

td:hover{
    background:blue;
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/LU9b7/1/

Comment: actually i m diong in smarty so i think there is problem with this

Comment: Thanks dear but now it will be oky